# Display multiple elements of an XML

Tags: xml, bash, xmllint

I have an xml file with multiple elements with the same key elements with the same name. I'm trying to concatonate the sub elements but can only get the first occurrence.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FOLDER JOBNAME="some Job"  MAXWAIT="5">
    <OTHER>
        <ELEMENTS>
        </ELEMENTS>
    </OTHER>
</FOLDER>
<FOLDER JOBNAME="some Other Job"  MAXWAIT="15">
    <OTHER>
        <ELEMENTS>
        </ELEMENTS>
    </OTHER>
</FOLDER>
```

Is there a way to use xmllint or some other tool to get output like:

```
some Job 5
some Other Job 15
etc...
```

when I try with `xmllint --xpath`, I get the following:

```
me@myComp tmp $ xmllint --xpath 'concat(//@JOBNAME," ",//@MAXWAIT)' jobs.xml
ADDRESS_VERIFICATION 5
me@myComp tmp $ xmllint --xpath 'concat(//JOBNAME[*]," ",//MAXWAIT[*])' jobs.xml
 
me@myComp tmp $
```

Is there a way to concatenate multiple parameters with `xmllint` or any other tool on the command line?

UPDATE - Yeah, it's a proper XML - Also, just notices the repeated lines and removed them.

Comment: This is not valix XML? you need to enclose with a `root` node

Comment: Please post valid XML.

Comment: Yeah, it's a valid XML. what is a "root" node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the XML parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) interesting:

```
$ xidel -s jobs.xml -e '//FOLDER/concat(@JOBNAME," ",@MAXWAIT)'
$ xidel -s jobs.xml -e '//FOLDER/join((@JOBNAME,@MAXWAIT))'
$ xidel -s jobs.xml -e '//FOLDER/x"{@JOBNAME} {@MAXWAIT}"'   # Xidel's own extended-string-syntax.
```

All resulting in:

```
some Job 5
some Other Job 15
```

Comment: Thank you my good sir. This does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have valid XML (per comments by @GillesQuenot and @Cyrus) and are open to using XSLT, then the following transform might be an option:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="FOLDER">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@JOBNAME, ' ', @MAXWAIT)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Sample usage:

```
$ xsltproc abc.xslt abc.txt

some Job 5
some Other Job 15
```

Comment: It's a valid XML. I only pasted part of it in my question. And, yes, I'm open to anything I can understand. So, how are you creating the abc.xslt file? I'm assuming the chunk from above is the contents of such a file, no? I'm entirely unfamiliar with what a "transform" is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: XSLT  is a language originally designed for transforming XML documents into other XML documents or other formats such as HTML for web pages, or in this case plain text.   `xsltproc` is a binary that applies an XSLT transform document to a source XML document to produce another format.  (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp)